# Basic Javascript - trying to implement a running total within a For loop

Tags: javascript

Pretty new to JS and I've been at this for a while. It nearly works, the issue is with the last couple of lines. I want to add the current value of x to a running total. x should only contain quantity * unitCost for the current iteration of the loop. I think it's just a small syntax error but every example I can find seems to use the same formatting as I do.

The console error I get in Chrome is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined".

```
var starters = ["tom_soup", "summer_salad", "fondue", "flatbread", "ahi_tatar"];
var startersLength = starters.length;

function calcOrderVal() {
var total;
for (var i = 0; i < startersLength; i++) {

    var x

    // retrieve individual cost of dish
    var unitCost = parseFloat(document.getElementById(starters[i]).getAttribute("data-price"));
    console.log("Cost of the unit is " + unitCost);

    // retrieve user-entered quantity
    var quantity = document.getElementById(starters[i]).value;
    console.log("Quantity required: " + quantity);

    // Multiply the cost by the quantity
    x = unitCost * quantity;
    console.log("Cost of this: " + x);

    // Add to running total
    total += parseFloat(x[i].value);
    console.log("Grand total: " + total);
```

Here's my HTML too if that's relevant:

```
<h1>Pre-order form</h1>
            <div class="qty">Quantity</div>

            <form>
                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Order from any of our starters: </legend>

                <div class="item">
                    <label class="starter" for="tom_soup">Roasted Tomato Soup served with goat cheese croutons and basil puree.</label>
                    <input type="text" id="tom_soup" class="txt" name="quantity" size="5" data-price="2.0" onkeydown="r2t()" onchange="calcOrderVal()">
                    <span class="num-error">Must be a non-negative integer</span>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <label class="starter" for="summer_salad">Summer Salad - organic butter lettuce with apples, blood oranges, and gorgonzola,
                        tossed with raspberry vinaigrette. </label>
                    <input type="text" id="summer_salad" class="txt" name="quantity" size="5" data-price="3.0" onkeydown="r2t()" onchange="calcOrderVal()">
                    <span class="num-error">Must be a non-negative integer</span>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <label class="starter" for="fondue">Fondue of Brie, Goat Cheese, and Gruyere with green apples and garlic crostini.</label>
                    <input type="text" id="fondue" class="txt" name="quantity" size="5" data-price="5.0" onkeydown="r2t()" onchange="calcOrderVal()">
                    <span class="num-error">Must be a non-negative integer</span>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <label class="starter" for="flatbread">Crispy Flatbread topped with asiago, prosciutto, and rocket. </label>
                    <input type="text" id="flatbread" class="txt" name="quantity" size="5" data-price="7.0" onkeydown="r2t()" onchange="calcOrderVal()">
                    <span class="num-error">Must be a non-negative integer</span>
                </div>

                <div class="item">
                    <label class="starter" for="ahi_tatar">Yellow-fin Ahi Tatar</label>
                    <input type="text" id="ahi_tatar" class="txt" name="quantity" size="5" data-price="11.0" onkeydown="r2t()" onchange="calcOrderVal()">
                    <span class="num-error">Must be a non-negative integer</span>
                </div>

                <div class="btn order">
                     <input type="submit" value="Order Now!" class="btn" name="subButton">&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
                    <input type="reset" value="Reset" class="btn" name="resetButton">
                </div>

                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

Comment: In your code, `x` is a number. What are you expecting the `x[i].value` in `total += parseFloat(x[i].value);` to do?

Comment: > The console error I get in Chrome is "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read
> property 'value' of undefined".

This means that some object on which you call `value` is `undefined` somewhere in your code. This happens when there is no element with such id. Usually the error message in browser console shows the file name and line number. You can click it and get to the problematic code part in the debugger. You can also put a breakpoint there, reload page, do the necessary actions and check the arguments it gets called with.

Comment: use jshint to validate your javascript. I saw that you are missing semicolon(;) after declaration of x ( var x).  Also try to use jsfiddle or jsbin to post your code which makes easier for rest of us who wants to help.

Comment: @N30: JavaScript has (the horror that is) Automatic Semicolon Insertion. That omission is in a place where ASI will fix it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to initialize total before adding something to it.

Try

```
var total = 0;
```

And

```
total += x;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
x = unitCost * quantity;
```

So `x` is a number, you then:

```
parseFloat(x[i].value);
```

But `x` is not an object/array and does not contain anything with a `Value` property.

Presumably you simply need to

```
total += x;
```

Comment: And initialize `total` to zero to start with.